# Too Many Arguments For Format String Error

Tags: java

I'm having problems with Format String.

I get the error that there are too many arguments in the format string(found 9, expected 8). I've tried reformatting other programs also but they are also giving the same error as this one.

The Code:

```
public class FormattingOutput {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String module1Name = "Mathematics", module2Name = "Introduction to Programming", module3Name = "Web Design";
        int module1Students = 64, module2Students = 84, module3Students = 62;
        float module1Mark = 72.031f, module2Mark = 61.845f, module3Mark = 72.774f;

        String formatString = String.format("%-35s%-10d%.1f\n%-35s%-10d.1f\n%-35s%-10d%.1f",module1Name,module1Students,module1Mark,module2Name,module2Students,module2Mark,module3Name,module3Students,module3Mark);

        System.out.println("Module Name                     #Students   Average Mark\n"   + formatString);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you have 8 %xxx and provide 9 replacements

Comment: It's because you specidify 9 arguments in your call to `String.format`, in addition to the first `String`, whereas you specify only 8 placeholders in the format string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

reformatted it:

```
String formatString = String.format("
%-35s
%-10d
%.1f\n
%-35s
%-10d.1f\n
%-35s
%-10d
%.1f",
module1Name,
module1Students,
module1Mark,
module2Name,
module2Students,
module2Mark,
module3Name,
module3Students,
module3Mark);
```

You forgot one '%' character, shouldn't it be:

```
String formatString = String.format("
%-35s
%-10d
%.1f\n
%-35s
%-10d
%.1f\n
%-35s
%-10d
%.1f",
module1Name,
module1Students,
module1Mark,
module2Name,
module2Students,
module2Mark,
module3Name,
module3Students,
module3Mark);
```

Comment: That's a nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 8 % characters, that means 8 arguments are expected.
But you provide 9

Comment: Jörns answr might be more comfortabel for you, but in future you may count the % , too If you dont have help from Björn

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your string is missing a `%` symbol in front of a `.1f`. `"%-35s%-10d%.1f\n%-35s%-10d.1f\n%-35s%-10d%.1f"` should be `"%-35s%-10d%.1f\n%-35s%-10d%.1f\n%-35s%-10d%.1f"`